# Hibernate second-level cache composite-id

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache, composite-primary-key

I am trying to cache an object in Hibernate's second level cache that has a composite-id mapped in my persistence-mapping file.  The logs say that the first time I run the query, the class mapped as the composite-id is put in the cache.  However, when I run the query a second time, the object is not pulled from the cache.  It is instead running the query again.

Does Hibernate have a problem with second-level caching composite ids?

Relevant info:

1. Using Hibernate 3.1, ehcache 2.4.2
2. Composite ID class implements serializable
3. I am using a new Hibernate session when running the query a second time
4. I am using hibernateTemplate.load(Class, ID) to retrieve the object

This is how I'm constructing my ID and executing my query:

```
CompositeId id = new CompositeId(date, sessionId);
UserDetails user = (UserDetails) hibernateTemplate.load(UserDetails.class, id);
```

And this is how my persistence-mapping file defines the above:

```
<class name="com.entities.UserDetails"
        table="USER_DETAILS" 
        lazy="false">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>

    <composite-id name="userId" class="com.entities.CompositeId" unsaved-value="undefined">
        <key-property name="userSessionId" column="SESSION_ID" />
        <key-property name="dateCreated" column="DATE_CREATED" type="date" />
    </composite-id>
```

EDIT:  The plot thickens....

When I changed this to read-only cache policy, it worked fine.  Transactional cache behavior seems to be extremely unpredictable.  Can anyone explain why the above happened with a read-write cache, yet worked fine with read-only?  This table is not being updated so not sure why transactional semantics would change things in that instance.

Comment: Do your composite id class has correctly implemented `equals()`/`hashCode()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should've added that also.  It implements both.

Comment: Are both the composite id and the entity Serializable?

Comment: Yes, they are both serializable

Comment: What specifically are you doing? How do you run your query and how do you put your object in cache? Are we talking about entity or query cache?

Comment: Please see my edits above, I added code samples.  This is the entity cache (2nd level, using ehcache)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a reported [bug with Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2668).  Seems that as a workaround, you *may* be able to successfully hit the cache if you use the same instance of your composite key, as opposed to one that is `.equals()`.

There is also a patch on the bug report, you could perhaps apply it yourself and roll your own patched Hibernate build.